# k3s - can't access from one pod to another if pods on different master nodes (HighAvailability setup)

Tags: kubernetes, k3s

k3s - can't access from one pod to another if pods on different nodes

---

Update:

I've narrowed the issue down - it's **pods that are on other master nodes that can't communicate with those on the original master**

pods on `rpi4-server1` - the original cluster - can communicate with pods on  `rpi-worker01` and `rpi3-worker02`

pods on `rpi4-server2` are unable to communicate with the others

I'm trying to run a [HighAvailability cluster with embedded DB](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/ha-embedded/) and using flannel / vxlan

---

I'm trying to setup a project with 5 services in k3s

When all of the pods are contained on a single node, they work together fine.

As soon as I add other nodes into the system and pods are deployed to them, the links seem to break.

In troubleshooting I've exec'd into one of the pods and tried to curl another. When they are on the same node this works, if the second service is on another node it doesn't.

I'm sure this is something simple that I'm missing, but I can't work it out! Help appreciated.

Key details:

- Using k3s and native traefik
- Two rpi4s as servers (High Availability) and two rpi3s as worker nodes
- metallb as loadbalancer
- Two services - `blah-interface` and `blah-svc` are configured as `LoadBalancer` to allow external access. The others `blah-server`, `n34` and `test-apis`as `NodePort` to support debugging, but only really need internal access

Info on nodes, pods and services....

```sh
pi@rpi4-server1:~/Projects/test_demo_2020/test_kube_config/testchart/templates $ sudo kubectl get nodes --all-namespaces -o wide
NAME           STATUS                     ROLES    AGE   VERSION         INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                         KERNEL-VERSION   CONTAINER-RUNTIME
rpi4-server1       Ready                      master   11h   v1.17.0+k3s.1   192.168.0.140   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.75-v7l+     docker://19.3.5
rpi-worker01   Ready,SchedulingDisabled   <none>   10h   v1.17.0+k3s.1   192.168.0.41    <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.66-v7+      containerd://1.3.0-k3s.5
rpi3-worker02    Ready,SchedulingDisabled   <none>   10h   v1.17.0+k3s.1   192.168.0.142   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.75-v7+      containerd://1.3.0-k3s.5
rpi4-server2         Ready                      master   10h   v1.17.0+k3s.1   192.168.0.143   <none>        Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)   4.19.75-v7l+     docker://19.3.5

pi@rpi4-server1:~/Projects/test_demo_2020/test_kube_config/testchart/templates $ sudo kubectl get pods --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE        NAME                                        READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE     IP              NODE           NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
kube-system      helm-install-traefik-l2z6l                  0/1     Completed   2          11h     10.42.0.2       rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
test-demo       n34-5c7b9475cb-zjlgl                      1/1     Running     1          4h30m   10.42.0.32      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
kube-system      metrics-server-6d684c7b5-5wgf9              1/1     Running     3          11h     10.42.0.26      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
metallb-system   speaker-62rkm                               0/1     Pending     0          99m     <none>          rpi-worker01   <none>           <none>
metallb-system   speaker-2shzq                               0/1     Pending     0          99m     <none>          rpi3-worker02    <none>           <none>
metallb-system   speaker-2mcnt                               1/1     Running     0          99m     192.168.0.143   rpi4-server2         <none>           <none>
metallb-system   speaker-v8j9g                               1/1     Running     0          99m     192.168.0.140   rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
metallb-system   controller-65895b47d4-pgcs6                 1/1     Running     0          90m     10.42.0.49      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
test-demo       blah-server-858ccd7788-mnf67         1/1     Running     0          64m     10.42.0.50      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
default          nginx2-6f4f6f76fc-n2kbq                     1/1     Running     0          22m     10.42.0.52      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
test-demo       blah-interface-587fc66bf9-qftv6               1/1     Running     0          22m     10.42.0.53      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
test-demo       blah-svc-6f8f68f46-gqcbw                    1/1     Running     0          21m     10.42.0.54      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
kube-system      coredns-d798c9dd-hdwn5                      1/1     Running     1          11h     10.42.0.27      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
kube-system      local-path-provisioner-58fb86bdfd-tjh7r     1/1     Running     31         11h     10.42.0.28      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
kube-system      traefik-6787cddb4b-tgq6j                    1/1     Running     0          4h50m   10.42.1.23      rpi4-server2         <none>           <none>
default          testdemo2020-testchart-6f8d44b496-2hcfc   1/1     Running     1          6h31m   10.42.0.29      rpi4-server1       <none>           <none>
test-demo       test-apis-75bb68dcd7-d8rrp                   1/1     Running     0          7m13s   10.42.1.29      rpi4-server2         <none>           <none>

pi@rpi4-server1:~/Projects/test_demo_2020/test_kube_config/testchart/templates $ sudo kubectl get svc --all-namespaces -o wide
NAMESPACE     NAME                       TYPE           CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP     PORT(S)                                        AGE     SELECTOR
default       kubernetes                 ClusterIP      10.43.0.1       <none>          443/TCP                                        11h     <none>
kube-system   kube-dns                   ClusterIP      10.43.0.10      <none>          53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP                         11h     k8s-app=kube-dns
kube-system   metrics-server             ClusterIP      10.43.74.118    <none>          443/TCP                                        11h     k8s-app=metrics-server
kube-system   traefik-prometheus         ClusterIP      10.43.78.135    <none>          9100/TCP                                       11h     app=traefik,release=traefik
test-demo    blah-server         NodePort       10.43.224.128   <none>          5055:31211/TCP                                 10h     io.kompose.service=blah-server
default       testdemo2020-testchart   ClusterIP      10.43.91.7      <none>          80/TCP                                         10h     app.kubernetes.io/instance=testdemo2020,app.kubernetes.io/name=testchart
test-demo    traf-dashboard             NodePort       10.43.60.155    <none>          8080:30808/TCP                                 10h     io.kompose.service=traf-dashboard
test-demo    test-apis                   NodePort       10.43.248.59    <none>          8075:31423/TCP                                 7h11m   io.kompose.service=test-apis
kube-system   traefik                    LoadBalancer   10.43.168.18    192.168.0.240   80:30688/TCP,443:31263/TCP                     11h     app=traefik,release=traefik
default       nginx2                     LoadBalancer   10.43.249.123   192.168.0.241   80:30497/TCP                                   92m     app=nginx2
test-demo    n34                      NodePort       10.43.171.206   <none>          7474:30474/TCP,7687:32051/TCP                  72m     io.kompose.service=n34
test-demo    blah-interface               LoadBalancer   10.43.149.158   192.168.0.242   80:30634/TCP                                   66m     io.kompose.service=blah-interface
test-demo    blah-svc                   LoadBalancer   10.43.19.242    192.168.0.243   5005:30005/TCP,5006:31904/TCP,5002:30685/TCP   51m     io.kompose.service=blah-svc
```

Comment: Its probably a firewall issue. If it's on a Raspberry, I have no idea, but you need to allow `ipip` protocol for pods to communicate with pods on other nodes.

Comment: I think k3s normally uses vxlan, so might be UDP port 8472 or 4789

Comment: What distro are you running it on?

Comment: I'm using Raspbian GNU/Linux 10 (buster) with [k3s default options - so flannel and vxlan](https://rancher.com/docs/k3s/latest/en/installation/network-options/)  - how would I troubleshoot whether the appropriate ports are open? I thought this was all configured during setup.

Comment: For HA you cannot use 2 servers. Its should be minimum "3" nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you issue could be related to the following [issue](https://github.com/rancher/k3s/issues/1613#issuecomment-647295522).
After configuring the network under **/etc/systemd/network/eth0.network** (filename may differ in your case, since i am using arch linux on all pis)

```
[Match] 
Name=eth0 
[Network]
Address=x.x.x.x/24 # ip of node
Gateway=x.x.x.x # ip of gateway router
Domains=default.svc.cluster.local svc.cluster.local cluster.local
DNS=10.x.x.x # k3s dns ip x.x.x.x # ip of gateway router
```

After that I removed the 10.x.x.x routes with `ip route del 10.x.x.x dev [flannel|cni0]` on every node and restarted them.